# converting a 64bit .so to 32bit

Tags: c, linux

I have a third party .so that was generated on a 64bit machine.  I'd like to use this same .so on a 32bit machine.  Anyone know how to do the conversion?  I tried:

```
objcopy "--input-target=elf64-x86-64" "--output-target=elf32-i386" 64bit.so 32bit.so
```

but I'm still getting "File format not recognized" from gcc.  For the record I'm doing this:

```
gcc -g code.c 32bit.so
```

which is kinda hack-y but that's ok for now.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You cannot run 64bit code on 32bit system. And I don't think there's a tool capable of converting machine code between architectures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.

You need to get 32bit version of this 3rd part library or recompile it from its sources